# How do I change the value in a dataframe's column based on another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I want to pass a function to a specific column:

[image]

Looking to change the 'Channel' column values based on certain requirements:

```
if 'Facebook' or 'FacebookPaid' or 'FacebookFree' in df['utm_Campaign']:
    df['Channel'] = 'FB'
elif 'Newsletter' in df['utm_Campaign']:
    df['Channel'] = 'Email'
else:
   if 'YoutubePaid' in df['utm_Campaign']:
                df['Channel'] = 'Youtube Direct'
```

Basically if there is a word 'Facebook' contained in another column (utm_Campaign) from the same row, the string in the 'Channel' column for the dataframe is set as 'FB'.

Not sure what to do. Do i map a function, or do a df.replace, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create conditions by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and then use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df['utm_Campaign'].str.contains('Facebook|FacebookPaid|FacebookFree')
m2 = df['utm_Campaign'].str.contains('Newsletter')
m3 = df['utm_Campaign'].str.contains('YoutubePaid')

df['Channel'] = np.select([m1,m2,m3], ['FB','Email','Youtube Direct'], default='no match')
```

Comment: I would... but I'm not the OP ;) haha

Comment: oops ;) It is Friday ;)

Comment: @jezrael hey man, I'm using your code and its working great, quick question though, let's say I want to apply your code above when the df['Platform'] column = 'iOS' only, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this:

```
df['Channel'] = ['FB' if 'Face' in row else df.iloc[i].Channel for i,row in enumerate(df.utm_Campaign)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you wanted to use apply:

```
df['Channel'] = df.apply(lambda df: \
    'FB' if df['utm_Campaign'].str.contains('Facebook') else \
    ('Email' if df['utm_Campaign'].str.contains('Newsletter') else \
    ('Youtube Direct' if df['utm_Campaign'].str.contains('YoutubePaid'))))
```